# How to refresh RecyclerView from another class without finish()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I create a fragment in `MainActivity` class, which shows RecyclerView with an ArrayList. In `NewNote` class I add a new item to list, and pass changed list to file on internal storage. When i back to `MainActivity` from `NewNote` after adding a new note, RecyclerView shows old list instead of the new one. When I restart my app, `MainActivity` shows new list thanks to onCreate method which load fragment again with a new list from internal storage.
My question is how to reload showing list, like when I restart my app. I read a lot similar problems on stack(in most answer was `notifyDataSetChanged()`) but i don't have idea what to do in my case, tried everything i've found.
Here's my code:

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FloatingActionButton addNewNoteButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmencik, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    addNewNoteButton = findViewById(R.id.add_new_note);
    addNewNoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewNote.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

`NewNote.java`

```
public class NewNote extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText text;
private ArrayList<Note> noteArrayList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_note_view);
    noteArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    text= findViewById(R.id.text);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
if(item.getIcon().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_save_white_36dp).getConstantState()))
    {
        Note note = new Note(text.getText().toString());
        addNewNoteToList(note);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void addNewNoteToList(Note note)
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("notes file", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("notes list", null);
    Type type= new TypeToken<ArrayList<Note>>() {}.getType();
    noteArrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    if(noteArrayList==null)
        noteArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    noteArrayList.add(note);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson2 = new Gson();
    String json2 = gson2.toJson(noteArrayList);
    editor.putString("notes list", json2);
    editor.apply();

}
}
```

`ListFragment.java`

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<Note> noteArrayList;
private ListAdapter listAdapter;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    loadArrayList();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerView);

    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(noteArrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    return view;
}

public void loadArrayList()
{

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("notes file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("notes list", null);
    Type type= new TypeToken<ArrayList<Note>>() {}.getType();
    noteArrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
}
```

`ListAdapter.java`

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Note> mCustomObjects;

public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private TextView mItemText;

    public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        mItemText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
        // mItemImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
    }}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int size=0;
    if(mCustomObjects!=null)
        size=mCustomObjects.size();
    return size;
}

public ListAdapter(ArrayList<Note> arrayList) {
    mCustomObjects = arrayList;
}

@Override
public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ListViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ListViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(mCustomObjects!=null) {
        Note note = mCustomObjects.get(position);
        holder.mItemText.setText(note.getText());
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

The first one. If you are going to add a new note but you have a return (Go back) button you can start an activityForResult and compare if the note has been added then refresh my list, is the user press return just do nothing.

The second one. You can post an event, using eventbus, to notify the recycler view that it has to be updated and then refresh the data.

I'm assuming you are using a swipe to refresh if not implement it. https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html

Comment: I was thinking about that idea with activityForResult, but what if user clicked not app's return button, but system's return button (like return button next to the home button in HTC) ? I'm struggling with that.

Comment: Override the onBackPressed to to the same action as the toolbar return

Comment: I didn't know that can override that button. Now it works and thak you! But... still i don't know how to solve my problem without finish. When i start `NewNote` activity, I don't call finish() in `MainActivity`. So `MainActivity` is still working, and I don't want to close it. 
From `NewNote` i want only add new note to list and then close it turning back to `MainActivity`, not starting a new activity.